# VeraCrypt won't automatically mount system favorites since upgrading Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mount, windows-10-upgrade, veracrypt

I recently upgraded my VeraCrypt-encrypted system to the latest Windows 10 version using [Windows 10 media patcher for upgrading VeraCrypt-encrypted systems](https://github.com/th-wilde/veracrypt-w10-patcher). Everything went fine, except the system favorite volumes aren't mounted automatically upon boot anymore. I didn't have this problem prior to upgrading the system.

I've tried removing the system favorites and re-adding them, to no avail. Any ideas?

EDIT: This question is not relevant to me anymore as I've switched to macOS entirely, but I'll leave it here in case people find answers for it. If anyone feels like it should be removed for that reason, feel free to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off Windows Fast Stratup, so that it loads VeraCrypt on startup.

Open `regedit` and go to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power`

Find:
`HiberbootEnabled DWORD`

Change `1` to `0` do disable

`0` = Turn off fast startup, `1` = Turn on fast startup.

Comment: I don't use Windows anymore (nor do I use VeraCrypt) so it's impossible for me to verify any new answers, but thanks for taking the time.